# Is it possible to get the size (in bytes) of the data, selected by 'SELECT' operator in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to get the size of the data selected by 'SELECT' operator in MYSQL? 
For example select * from sometable where user_id =33; I need to limit size per user.

Comment: Please elaborate on your requirement.  Supposing the size is too large, what would you do since knowing the size would depend in the first place on running the query?  Off the top of my head, you could check the size of data in the app layer.

Comment: then don't use `SELECT *`, select the data you actually need

Comment: you can use `char_length(column)+char_length(column1)+....` .

Comment: i think you need a count of selected records? iam correct

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what you are actually trying to do. Answering such a vague question does not make much sense.

Comment: I mean, there is a table for user's data, users can store a lot of data, i want to limit it by size, for example just 10MB for one user. In phpMyAdmin I can see how much size of whole table is taken, but I need to know part size, just for one user (user_id). I know about char_length(column)+char_length(column1), but I thought there is some function, like COUNT, which calculates the size.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want?

If you want to know the size of a result, just get is and use whatever language you're using to figure out how large the result is. In php you can use length() to get the lenght of a string. Though this will not work for numbers and will not give you the exact size in bytes that are stored in the database. Why is this of importance? How mysql stores data and how much bytes this uses, is normally of no importance.

Then you say you "need to limit size per user". Why? What size do you need to limit? There are datatypes in mysql and for example varchar can be made to only contain a specific length. So if you want a field to be of type varchar and contain max 20 chars, then define your table accordingly

```
CREATE TABLE sometable (
  somefield varchar(20),
   ...
```